# Problem programming and running STM32F103C8

Tags: stm32, keil, iar, stm32f1

I'm facing an unexpected problem with stm32f103c8. I'm programming the chip and after reset, it starts to run the program, but after a few seconds the microcontroller getting mixed up and stops running the program. After that when I try to reprogram the microcontroller, IDE(IAR EWARM) tells "target held in reset state".
It's very unusual issue because sometimes when I connect nRST pin directly to the VCC(3.3V), microcontroller runs program but unfortunately the current goes over 120mA and chip breaks down finally.
I'm using STM32CubeMX to generate the codes and my programmer is STLINK V2(clone), also tried Jlink V8.0(clone) but didn't change the result.

Could it be because of the clone programmers?

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Never connect nRST directly to VDD/VCC.  This is a bi-directional input-output which must only ever be connected to an open-drain/open-collector signal.  It can be pulled low externally or from within, it must never ever be pulled or driven high other than by the internal pull-up resistor.

When your debugger or programmer has finished programming the flash and wants to start running the new program then it requires to be able to pull this line low, which it might do externally if you connect this line to it in hardware, or else it has to be able to pull it low by software using the internal reset pulse-generator.  If it does this and you have tied the line high externally then you are effectively shorting out your power supply, which is the cause of the over-current condition that you have observed.

Maybe the original problem is that your counterfeit ST-Link has its reset output configured as push-pull when it should be open-drain.

I would suggest that the easiest way to proceed is to leave the nRST line unconnected and configure your programming tool to use a software reset only.